# What is the actual definition of a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I am learning precalculus and my book defines the following:

> A function $f$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is a rule that assigns to every element $a$ in $A$ one and only one value in $B$.

Well, I am thinking, a rule isn't something that I've seen defined mathematically. So what is a function, really? Is it a subset of $A\times B$ or something?

Comment: What are your thoughts after [reading the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition)?

Comment: The proper term for rule is ["Relation"](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: No offense, but you really shouldn't worry about the definition of a function at the pre-calculus level.  Having previously taught pre-calculus, you are _not_ going to be taught what a function is and you are _not_ going to be expected to _know_ what a function really is.  You are going to be taught a bunch of things that are _not_ what functions are.  If you are really interested then I would hold off until you take a discrete mathematics course in college where functions/relations will be dealt with properly (because I guarantee they _won't_ in even an advanced high school course).

Comment: p.s. Note that the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) uses discrete domains to illustrate functions (which is the proper way to introduce functions).  This will not help you whatsoever in any of the "pre-cal" questions you are going to receive about functions (which are flawed).  You are going to be asked things like "what is the domain of this function"--which is an invalid question on the face of things because something is _not_ a function until _you_ tell me its domain (_and_ range!--although asking for the _image is_ a valid question).

Comment: @Jared: Your comment is utterly condescending and detrimental.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter OK, but my comment represents the reality of secondary education.  The OP asked about "precalculus" and whether you like it or not, the way functions are taught in high school precalculus classes are horribly misleading.  Perhaps the OP is asking for a more in depth explanation (that's fine and I am glad that answers/comments here give that explanation), _however_ the explanations given _will not_ help the OP understand function/domain/range questions that will be asked in a high school precalculus course (because the questions that are going to be asked are flawed).

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Here is an example: a typical question about "functions" in a precalculus course will be _Given $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ what is the domain and range of $f(x)$?_  This is a _flawed_ question that ultimately has _nothing_ to do with functions.  In reality the question is asking, given that the domain and range is the largest possible set of real numbers, what is the domain and _image_ of this function?  However, we would _never_ ask this question in this way instead, just assume that students will assume this (which means they have no understanding of functions).

Comment: Please refer to Alex M.'s answer. By far the best.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, a function is a subset of $A \times B$ with the following very important property: for every $x \in A$, there exist a **unique** $y \in B$ such that $(x,y) \in A \times B$. Intuitively, this tells you that a function cannot take an element $x$ into several distinct values $y$ - that wouldn't be a function anymore, but somehing called "binary relation" (that you need not worry about).

Nevertheless, for many practical purposes, thinking of a function as a rule, or a correspondence between $x$ values and $y$ values, will suffice. Still, keep the correct definition somewhere in the back of your mind, readily available if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @AlexM Would it be more practical to think of a function as an mathematical object used to model rules in real life?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a subset R of $A \times B$ such that for every $a \in A$ there is exactly one $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in R$. So, it's a special kind of binary relation, and since for every $a \in A$ there is one and only $b \in B$ that gets 'associated'/'paired' with this $a$, we can call that the 'function value' of $a$. This is what your textbook means by a function being a kind of a rule that 'assigns' a specific $b$ to any $a$ ... and as such we can say that $f(a) = b$

Interestingly, there are also things called '[partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)', that assign *at most* one $b \in B$ to every $a \in A$ .. if there is no $b \in B$ that gets paired with some a in A, then we say that the function value $f(a)$ is undefined. So, strictly speaking, a partial function is not a function .. though it shares the important idea with a function that there cannot be more than two different elements $b_1 \in B$ and $b_2 \in B$ associated or assigned to any $a \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Alex M. has given the standard definition of a function in "material set theory". In material set theory, everything is a set, and there is a single global relation $\in$. If you're working in material set theory, you must be able to boil down every possible statement into a statement involving $\in$ (and $=$, though it's even possible to get rid of $=$ if you try hard enough).

First, we prove that for all $a, b$, there is a unique $c$ such that for all $x$, $x \in c$ if and only if $x = a$ or $x = b$.

We then introduce the notation $\{a, b\}$ to represent this $c$. Note that if we have any statement involving the set $\{a, b\}$ (a statement $\phi(\{a, b\})$), we can always rewrite the statement to not use the notation $\{a, b\}$ by rewriting as "There is some $c$ such that for all $x$, $x \in c$ if and only if either $x = a$ or $x = b$, and furthermore $\phi(c)$".

Then, we introduce the notation $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ (here, by $\{a\}$, we technically mean $\{a, a\}$). Note that $(a, b) = (c, d)$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d$. Once again, we can rewrite any statement involving the ordered pair $(a, b)$ to not involve this ordered pair - just substituting $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$. We can then take this statement and, using the above translation scheme, rewrite it to use only $\in$.

The statement "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$" can thus be written as

$$[\forall x . (x \in f \to \exists a . a \in A \land \exists b . b \in B \land (a, b) = x)] \land \forall x . x \in A \to \exists y . y \in B \land (x, y) \in f \land \forall y' . (x, y') \in f \to y = y'$$

though of course, this is only shorthand for a much longer and more complicated statement which doesn't use ordered pair notation.

In more convenient notation (involving more definitional extensions), we can write the definition of "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$" as

$$f \subseteq A \times B \land \forall x \in A . \exists! y \in B . (x, y) \in f$$

This requires extending the language to include the Cartesian product $\times$ and also the subset symbol $\subseteq$.

Note that when we make some statement about $f(x)$ in material set theory, we must be able to rewrite this statement to avoid using this notation. So $\phi(f(x))$ becomes the statement $\exists y . (x, y) \in f \land \phi(y)$.

However, in structural versions of set theory (such as ETCS), functions are actually primitive entities. Note I'm not considering SEAR here, only category-theoretic notions of set theory.

In structural set theory, there are two kinds of things. First, there are sets. Second, for any sets $A, B$, there are functions $f : A \to B$.

Instead of $\in$ being the primitive notion, the basic notion in structural is the notion of function composition. One starts with the notion of functions and function composition and then supposes the existence of a "one-element set" $1$ (where "one-element set" is defined purely in terms of functions, not elements). An element of a set $A$ is defined to be a function $a : 1 \to A$. If we have an element $a : 1 \to A$ and a function $f : A \to B$, then we see that $f \circ a : 1 \to B$. We define $f(a)$ to be $f \circ a$. This means that every function $f$ gives rise to a "rule" which takes an element of $A$ and outputs an element of $B$.

Note that function composition is, in practice, how almost all functions are defined. For example, consider the function $f(x, y) = \cos{\sin(x + y)}$. This is just $f = \cos \circ \sin \circ +$ - the definition is purely in terms of function compositions. Whenever we define functions using an explicit equation and other functions, we are using composition. So it makes sense to take function composition as the basic notion.

Conversely, we can specify $A \times B$ purely in terms of functions, and we can also define a notion of $\subseteq$ purely in terms of functions. We can then prove that for every $G \subseteq A \times B$, if for all $a \in A$, there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a, b) \in G$, then there is a unique function $f : A \to B$ such that for all $a \in A$, $(a, f(a)) \in G$. This means that every definable "rule" that, given an $a \in A$, specifies a unique $b \in B$ gives rise to a function which takes as an input the $a \in A$ and outputs the specified $b$.

So functions $A \to B$ are in bijective correspondence with their graphs $G \subseteq A \times B$, but the two are not definitionally the same thing. The notion of the graph of a function $f : A \to B$ - that is, $\{(a, f(a)) \mid a \in A\} \subseteq A \times B$ - is subsidiary to the notion of a function itself, which is the primitive and basic notion.

Let's return to the question of "what is a function?" In material set theory, because the defining notion is that of elementhood, we have to come up with an encoding for the intuitive idea that a function is a rule associating every possible input with exactly 1 output. We do this by defining a notion of "ordered pair" and then identifying a function $f : A \to B$ with its graph $\{(x, f(x)) \mid x \in A\}$.

By contrast, in structural set theory, we take functions themselves as a primitive notion. The only answer to the question "what is a function?" is an intuitive, informal answer. This is perfectly analogous to asking the question "what is a set?" in material set theory. We can't define a set in terms of the things which exist in material set theory, since the only things that exist in material set theory are sets.

Comment: This is unhelpful. An intuitive answer is necessarily not the correct answer, because an intuitive notion of what a function is cannot constitute a definition, even in principle. Also, asking "what is a function?" is not analogous to asking "what is a set?" in material set theory. It is merely asking what kind of set it is. It is a collection of Kuratowski pairs satisfying the axioms that Alex M. explained in his comment. You make the distinction between a graph and a function, even though in material set theory, no such a distinction even exists, and you are treating structural set theory...

Comment: ...as the true set theory, even though this is not the case, and the choice is arbitrary. Besides, both theories are equivalent and equiconsistent.

Comment: @Angel Just as there is no definition of "set" in material set theory, there is no definition of "function" in structural set theory. A definition must refer to more primitive concepts, and in structural set theory, a function is the most primitive concept. Thus, the question "what is a function?" in structural set theory is perfectly analogous to "what is a set?" in material set theory. I am not treating either version of set theory as the "true version"; I discuss them on their own merits. By contrast, you are treating material set theory as the true set theory.

Comment: @Angel The advantage to taking functions as a primitive notion is: what if someone defines a function $f : A \to B$ as a subset of $B \times A$ satisfying some conditions rather than of $A \times B$? They'd be able to do all the same mathematics that we do, but you and this other person would each believe that the other is proving completely different theorems. By contrast, taking functions as a primitive notion means that there is no possibility of such a conflict.

Comment: You are being dishonest. I never said material set theory is the true set theory. In fact, I explicitly stated that both theories are equivalent, and that the choice between one and the other is arbitrary. Also, I never denied any advantages that treating functions as a primitive notion would have. Advantages and disadvantages exist to both. I do no tolerate any dishonesty whatsoever.

Comment: @Angel I didn’t say you explicitly claimed that material set theory is the true set theory. I said you treat it as if it is the true set theory. When you say asking “what is a function?” is merely asking “what kind of set it is”, you are completely dismissing structural set theory as a candidate for the true set theory. All I have done is present both perspectives. You are claiming that the structural perspective - that a function is a primitive notion, and hence has no formal definition - is “necessarily not the correct answer”.

Comment: @MarkSaving: This is a very respectable answer, but take a look at the OP's first words: *"I am learning precalculus"*. I believe that this is overkill for a beginner who just wants to understand the connection between some formal concept of "function" and the usual intuitive understanding of "function" as "procedure to follow to get a result from given data" (such as in, for instance, functions in programming languages).

Comment: @AlexM. In that case, I would say that trying to answer the question in terms of a formal definition of Kuratowski ordered pairs is also overkill. Also, I think it's extremely relevant to present the idea that the most important part of the idea of a "function" is function composition, since this is, in practice, how almost all functions are defined. Given that the question is explicitly philosophical - "So what is a function, really?" - I think presenting only one view on the subject would be a missed opportunity, especially since every other answer presented only the material perspective.